# React Native devices not showing up

Tags: react-native

I've been working with React Native  on windows 10 system. AM trying with Emulator and Physical Device as well. But it showing Below Error Message.

[React Native devices not showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHoDM.png)

Answer (score 2):

You should go to

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
```

and run the following command

```
./sdkmanager --licenses
```

Comment: thanks for your reply . i got below error message now 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: I guess there's a bug raising the exception . Please check the code .

Comment: i taken new appliation this problem is solved. application running but in emulator its showing The development server returned response error code: 500

URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false
and some body of appliation urls shwoing

Comment: Glad that things went well with you . Please feel free to mark the answer as correct .

Comment: i unable to solve the the above problem am getting the below message

Comment: The development server returned response error code: 500

URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

Body:
{"originModulePath":"D:\\application\MobileApp\\TheBlue\\App.js","targetModuleName":"./../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js","message":"Unable to resolve module `./../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js`